# How to make and implement custom tooltip with attached property of Title and Description in WinUI-3 C#?

Tags: c#, winui-3

custom class name - CustomToolTip

Attached properties - Title and Description

*I expecting like in WinUI-3 MainWindow.xaml:*

```
 <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="radRibbonView"> 
    <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Home"> 
        <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="radRibbonGroupClipboard"  
                                ribbon:ScreenTip.Description="Show the Clipboard Task options." 
                                ribbon:ScreenTip.Title="Clipboard" /> 
    </ribbon:RibbonGroup  > 
 </ribbon:RibbonTab >
`
```

Comment: now i changed telerik as a ribbon. How to implement to a custom tooltip with these attached properties in WinUI-3.                                                                            Note :  ribbon is a namespace of the all custom classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option using an **AttachedProperty**.

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TipTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TipTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Button
            local:ScreenTip.Description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            local:ScreenTip.Placement="Bottom"
            local:ScreenTip.Title="LOREM IPSUM"
            Content="Click" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**ScreenTip.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Text;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

namespace TipTests;

public class ScreenTip
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Title",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ScreenTip),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTitlePropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Description",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ScreenTip),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnDescriptionPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlacementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Placement",
            typeof(PlacementMode),
            typeof(ScreenTip),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, OnPlacementPropertyChanged));

    public static string GetTitle(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(TitleProperty);

    public static void SetTitle(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);

    public static string GetDescription(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(DescriptionProperty);

    public static void SetDescription(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);

    public static PlacementMode GetPlacement(DependencyObject obj) => (PlacementMode)obj.GetValue(PlacementProperty);

    public static void SetPlacement(DependencyObject obj, PlacementMode value) => obj.SetValue(PlacementProperty, value);

    private static void OnTitlePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tip tip = GetTip(d);
        tip.TitleTextBlock.Text = e.NewValue as string ?? string.Empty;
        tip.TitleTextBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;

        // Getting the parent.
        if (d is Button parent)
        {
            // Do something.
        }
    }

    private static void OnDescriptionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tip tip = GetTip(d);
        tip.DescriptionTextBlock.Text = e.NewValue as string ?? string.Empty;
        tip.DescriptionTextBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    }

    private static void OnPlacementPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is PlacementMode placement)
        {
            ToolTipService.SetPlacement(d, placement);
        }
    }

    private static Tip GetTip(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        if (ToolTipService.GetToolTip(dependencyObject) is not Tip tip)
        {
            tip = new Tip();
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(dependencyObject, tip);
        }

        return tip;
    }

    private class Tip : Grid
    {
        public Tip()
        {
            this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)
            });

            Grid.SetRow(this.TitleTextBlock, 0);
            this.Children.Add(this.TitleTextBlock);

            this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star)
            });

            Grid.SetRow(this.DescriptionTextBlock, 1);
            this.Children.Add(this.DescriptionTextBlock);
        }

        public TextBlock TitleTextBlock { get; } = new();

        public TextBlock DescriptionTextBlock { get; } = new();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we retrieve the parent of our custom tooltip class from this?

Comment: By "parent" you mean the ``Button`` in this example?

Comment: Yes . I am using custom buttons. like custom toggle button, split button, dropdown button, combo box. without specifying and binding to mainwindow.xaml . Is it possible to retrieve the parent in the custom ToolTip class?. I tried to retrieve screentip parents but it shows null.                                                                     Dependency object as Button . Can get from it as screentip parent?                                      or any other solution ?

Comment: I updated with a code to get the parent. See ``OnTitlePropertyChanged``.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to the Telerik ScreenTip, you should try the built-in `ToolTip`.

```xml
<Button
    Content="Click"
    ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                FontWeight="SemiBold"
                Text="Some Title" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: It's ok. So, in my custom tooltip control, I only need to specify the attached title and description properties in my MainWindow.xaml page. I have a style of customization tooltip. But I want to implement with an attached property. Please help me? like above ribbon:ScreenTip.Title . ribbon is a namespace of the all custom classes.